# How to turn on/off all sounds from accessibility settings programmatically in android?

Tags: android, audio, accessibility

In Android 4.0+ there is an option Settings->Accessibility-> Turn of all sounds. 
If I check that option, any application running on the android device will not produce any sound at all.
My application has to give alarm sound, so if someone has checked that option, the app does not give any sound.
So, I have to automatically un-check that option every time user launches the application.
Through code, how can I do that?

It will be helpful if someone can share a piece of code. I have tried AudioManager, but that only works if mobile audio is enabled.

```
amanger.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

amanger.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);

amanger.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    (int)(amanger.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)*(75.0/100.0)), 0);
```

Comment: There is no "Settings->Accessibility->Turn of all sounds" option in stock Android. This is a vendor customization, and there is probably no way around it. Additionally, if the user has specified "turn off sounds" for accessibility reasons, you should respect their preference and find some other way to alert them without using sound.

Comment: I can buy that advice.Thank you.

Comment: Hey @alanv, I'd recommend you post that as an answer. While it doesn't actually solve the OP's original question, it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following function to disable system volume

```
public static void disableSound(Context context)
 {
     AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0, 0);
 }
```

If you want to enable it again, just change the parameters

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 10, 0);
```

Volume ranges from 0-10

Comment: " AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM " may help you

Comment: Sorry. I feel you did not quite understand my query.